# Get the value from a clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a keyboard on my screen. Right now I am getting back the value of each letter when clicked  through the function getLetter, but I need to grab that value and use it instead of `prompt()[0]`. So I want my input to be the actual letter ("A" or "B" or...). The problem is that I am not being able to put that value in the input variable. How do I do this?

```
abc = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
               'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

$('#letters').text('');
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  var div = $('<div>').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
  div.html(abc[i]);
  div.on('click', getLetter); 
  var newDiv = $('#letters').append(div);
}
$('body').append(newDiv);     


function getLetter() {
  $(this).text();
  this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  this.style.cursor = 'default';
  this.onclick = null;
}

while(!game.isOver()) {
  var input = prompt()[0];
  game.guess(input);
  $('p').text(game.render());  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the contents of the while loop into the `getLetter()` function, and remove the while loop because it is useless now: you don't want to do anything until the user clicks a button.

```
function getLetter() {
  var input=$(this).text();
  this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  this.style.cursor = 'default';
  this.onclick = null;
  game.guess(input);
  $('p').text(game.render()); 
}
```